# If or case statement based on radio button click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to find a way to run some code based on the selection of a radio button. I have several radio buttons in a groupbox which will run different code based on there selection. Now, being a fairly new user to VB.NET, I am struggling to correctly code this.

Would I be better to use an IF statement or a SELECT CASE statement. I have tried using a flag set as a  boolean to indicate if button1 is selected, set flag = true. That is as far as I have got. I am using CheckedChanged event to handle to event changes. I have included some code and would be grateful if someone could start me off. Many thanks.

```
Private Sub rdbBoxReturn_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbBoxReturn.CheckedChanged

'code goes here
 flagBoxReturn = True

End Sub


Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Try

            If flagBoxReturn = True Then
                MessageBox.Show(CStr(flagBoxReturn))
                Return

            Else

                DBConnection.connect()
                sql = "SELECT MAX([Id]) from Request Boxes WHERE Customer = '" & cmbCustomer.Text & "' "

                'MessageBox.Show(cmbCustomer.Text)
                'sql = "INSERT INTO [Requests]  ("")"
                'Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from Boxes WHERE Customer = ? AND Status = 'i'"

                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

                Dim id As String
                Dim requestor As String = "DEMO"
                Dim intake As String = "I"
                Dim status As String = "O"

                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cmbCustomer.Text)

                cmd.CommandText = sql
                cmd.Connection = oledbCnn
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


                'lvSelectRequestItems.Items.Clear()

                While dr.Read()

                    id = CStr(CInt(dr.Item(0).ToString))
                    id = String.Format("{0:D6}", (Convert.ToInt32(id) + 1))
                    'id = CStr(CDbl(id) + 1)

                End While

                MessageBox.Show(CStr(id))

                dr.Close()

                sql = "INSERT INTO [Request Boxes] ([Request no], Customer, Dept, [Type], [Service level], [Date-time received], [Received by], [Date-time due], Quantity, [Cust requestor], Status ) " &
                "VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & cmbCustomer.Text.ToUpper & "', '" & cmbDept.Text & "', '" & intake.ToString & "', '" & rbServiceLevel.ToString & "', '" & dtpDateReceived.Value & "', '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & dtpDateDue.Value & "', '" & txtBoxQuantity.Text & "', '" & requestor.ToString & "', '" & status & "')"

                cmd.CommandText = sql
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                cmd.Dispose()
                oledbCnn.Close()

                flagBoxReturn = False

                MessageBox.Show("Your record number: " & id & " Was entered successfully")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a question about how to set the flag or it is about the save code (very unsecure and weak)

Comment: @Steve How to set flag

Comment: ';DROP TABLE Request; SELECT 'Someone needs to learn about SQL Injection

Comment: @Dan-o I know about sql injection and wasn't asking about sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
Public Enum SaveOption As Int32
  DoNothing = 0
  DoSomething = 1    '  Obviously rename this to something that makes sense in your situation.
End Enum

Public Function GetSaveOption() As SaveOption
  Dim result As SaveOption = SaveOption.DoNothing

  If rdbBoxReturn.Checked Then
    result = DoSomething
  End If
  '  Add as many if statements her to cover all your radio buttons.

  Return result
End Function



Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
  Select Case GetSaveOption
    Case SaveOption.DoNothing
      Exit Sub

    Case SaveOption.DoSomething
      ' Your save code here
  End Select
End Sub
```

This method makes your code more readable by converting UI element states into program states.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement is better if the number of comparisons is small
if you had a radio button list control, that would be much better as in that case
switch statement can be passed the index variable (SelectedIndex property of the radio
button list) but that control is available in web forms, or can be available in win forms
if you find some free user/custom control etc.

so in your case, better to use if else statements